# Error while posting on Facebook using Facebook Graph v5 sdk

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph v5 sdk for login and posting on wall but gets some errors. I've successful login and gets users details like age, birthday etc. successfully but while on posting on facebook using this code

`$fb->post('/me/feed', $attachment, $accessToken)`;

gets some permissions errors as below.

**Error**:
    Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthorizationException: (#200) Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission

index.php

```
<?php

    require_once "config.php";
    $redirectURL = "http://localhost/fbLogin/fb-callback.php";
    $permissions = ['email, user_birthday,user_posts,manage_pages,publish_pages'];
    $loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl($redirectURL, $permissions);
    echo $loginURL;
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.location = "<?php echo $loginURL; ?>";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

fb-callback.php

```
<?php
    require_once "config.php";

    try {
        $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();

    } catch(\fbLogin\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();

    } catch(\fbLogin\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $d) {
        echo $d->getMessage();
        exit();

    }
    if (!isset($accessToken)) {
      if ($helper->getError()) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
        echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
        echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
        echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
      } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
        echo 'Bad request';
      }
      exit;
    }

    // Logged in
    echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
    var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

    // The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
    $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

    // Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
    $tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
    echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
    var_dump($tokenMetadata);

    // Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
    $tokenMetadata->validateAppId('371331840061100'); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
    // If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
    //$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
    $tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

    if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
      // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
      try {
        $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
      } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $e->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
        exit;
      }

      echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
      var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
    }

    $_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
    $respose = $fb->get("/me?fields=id,name,email,first_name,last_name,address,hometown,gender,birthday,posts", $accessToken);
    // Get the base class GraphNode from the response
    $graphNode = $respose->getGraphNode();
    // Get the response typed as a GraphUser
    $user = $respose->getGraphUser();
    echo $user->getName();
    echo $user->getEmail();
    echo $user->getBirthday()->format('m/d/y');
    echo $graphNode->getField('country');
    echo $user->getHomeTown();
    echo $user->getGender();

    echo $_SESSION['fb_access_token'];
    header('Location: http://localhost/fblogin/home.php');
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php

    session_start();
    require_once "Facebook/autoload.php";
    $fb  = new \Facebook\Facebook([

            'app_id' => '371331840061100',
            'app_secret' =>'fc535825bfe084a63c33a6d36648ddff',
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10'

        ]);
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

?>
```

home.php

```
<?php
    require_once "config.php";
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>wlecom</h1>

<?php



    $message = "test message";

    $attachment = array('message' => $message);

    try{

        $accessToken = $_SESSION['fb_access_token'];

             // Post to Facebook
        $fb->post('/me/feed', $attachment, $accessToken);

        // Display post submission status
        echo 'The post was published successfully to the Facebook timeline.';

    }catch(FacebookResponseException $e){
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }catch(FacebookSDKException $e){
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;


    } catch(\fbLogin\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();

    } catch(\fbLogin\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $d) {
        echo $d->getMessage();
        exit();
    }


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to post on a user wall with a token that does not include the `publish_actions` permission.

You should read the changelog about `publish_actions` first though: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes